# Querying for a relationship field

Tags: relationships, query, html

I am building a web portal to display a list of servers and their designated applications in an HTML table. The channel I am using for the parent is called 'servers'. Inside this channel, I have a field called 'server_application' with a type Relationship that is pulling the options from another channel called 'system'. The field in that channel I am looking to grab is called 'system_short_name' and will be ultimately what I want to show on the webpage. How do I query for this? Are there parent IDs that I need to match in a SELECT statement? Below is a snippet of the HTML I am using to display the data. The table row that reads {server_application} is where the issue is. It does not know where I am trying to grab that field entry from.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="servers"}
 <tr>
      <td><a href="{url_title_path='site/server_detail'}">{title}</a></td>
       <td>{server_ip_address}</td>
       <td>{server_application}</td>
       <td>{server_environment}</td>
       <td>{server_deployment_date format="%M %j %Y"}</td>
 </tr>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/fieldtypes/relationships.html#accessing-children

To access the child entry to your Servers channel, just loop over the field like so:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="servers"}

    {server_application}
        Title : {server_application:title} <br/>
        Short Name : {server_application:system_short_name}
    {/server_application}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Thank you!!! That was quick and resolved it for me.